# External JSON Request to WebApi2 not working

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api

I made a webservice with webApi2 and released it on my IIS.

You can put in a number and the number is then saved to an SQL Database.

Now I want to call this Service from another Website but here I am stuck.

The JSON post doesn't work and, as I am still a beginner, I don't get why.

Here you can find the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title></title>
<link href="http://195.2.164.73:9081/Content/css?v=WMr-pvK-ldSbNXHT-    cT0d9QF2pqi7sqz_4MtKl04wlw1" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://195.2.164.73:9081/bundles/modernizr?    v=qVODBytEBVVePTNtSFXgRX0NCEjh9U_Oj8ePaSiRcGg1"></script>

</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<body>
<header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="float-left">
<p class="site-title">
<a href="/">ASP.NET Web API</a></p>
</div>
<div class="float-right">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="/">Startseite</a></li>
<li><a href="/Help">API</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<div id="body">
<ul id="contacts"></ul>
</div>

<form id="saveContactForm" method="post">
<h3>Create a new Contact</h3>
<p>
<label for="contactName">Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="Number" />
</p>
<input type="button" id="saveContact" value="Save" />
</form>




<script src="http://195.2.164.73:9081//bundles/jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-    kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#saveContact').click(function () {
$.post("195.2.164.73:9081/api/contact",
$("#saveContactForm").serialize(),
function (value) {
$('#contacts').append('<li>' + "test"+ '</li>');
},
"json"
);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Enable CORS was the thing that helped me here.

The Cross site scripting was the problem here.